# How to adjust color palette with customized breaks in tmap?

Tags: r, tmap, colorbrewer

I would like to plot 1950 world population in density map with tmap package.
And I break the population data into 22 categories manually, and fill with different color for each category.
My code is:

```
    library(tmap)
    data(World)

    map <- tm_shape(World)+
                  tm_fill("1950", 
                  title = "Population class",
                  breaks = c(0, 100 ,200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,
                             1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800,
                             1900, 2000, 3000, 4000),
                  textNA = "No data",
                  colorNA = "white", 
                  palette = "topo")+
              tm_borders()+
              tm_layout("World Density Population Map")
              tm_style_classic()
    current.mode <- tmap_mode("plot")
    map
```

And error occurred at the last step "map":

> Error: Invalid palette

I had a public dataset from wpp2015 which is not exactly same as my dataset but will provide an intuition of my data frame structure.

```
     dput(df) <- structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 8L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 21L, 190L, 28L, 29L, 146L, 31L, 19L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 32L, 37L, 201L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 134L, 49L, 58L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 22L, 59L, 61L, 65L, 67L, 68L, 71L, 69L, 70L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 60L, 78L, 80L, 79L, 203L, 81L, 82L, 108L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 90L, 91L, 93L, 44L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 51L, 103L, 104L, 106L, 105L, 107L, 57L, 173L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 115L, 116L, 113L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 124L, 45L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 136L, 141L, 174L, 142L, 144L, 145L, 160L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 54L, 9L, 150L, 231L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 158L, 138L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 170L, 89L, 214L, 171L, 172L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 202L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 233L, 189L, 191L, 194L, 241L, 200L, 196L, 205L, 237L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 213L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 223L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 212L, 66L, 224L, 41L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 30L, 229L, 230L, 232L, 180L, 239L, 240L, 238L, 143L, 117L, 2L, 112L, 156L, 63L, 72L, 159L, 62L, 140L, 155L, 197L, 234L, 36L, 38L, 193L, 192L, 235L, 64L, 157L, 199L, 236L, 12L, 135L, 195L, 161L, 10L, 114L, 204L, 118L, 137L, 169L, 122L, 123L, 228L, 92L, 139L, 39L, 198L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Africa", "Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Asia", "Australia", "Australia/New Zealand", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Caribbean", "Central African Republic", "Central America", "Central Asia", "Chad", "Channel Islands", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "China, Macao SAR", "China, Taiwan Province of China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Curacao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Dem. People's Rep. of Korea", "Dem. Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", "Eastern Africa", "Eastern Asia", "Eastern Europe", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Europe", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "High-income countries", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Dem. Republic", "Latin America and the Caribbean", "Latvia", "Least developed countries", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Less developed regions", "Less developed regions, excluding China", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania", "Low-income countries", "Lower-middle-income countries", "Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Melanesia", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Micronesia (Fed. States of)", "Middle-income countries", "Middle Africa", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "More developed regions", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Northern Africa", "Northern America", "Northern Europe", "Norway", "Oceania", "Oman", "Other less developed countries", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Polynesia", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Samoa", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South-Central Asia", "South-Eastern Asia", "South Africa", "South America", "South Sudan", "Southern Africa", "Southern Asia", "Southern Europe", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", "State of Palestine", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Tajikistan", "TFYR Macedonia", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United Republic of Tanzania", "United States of America", "United States Virgin Islands", "Upper-middle-income countries", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", "Viet Nam", "Western Africa", "Western Asia", "Western Europe", "Western Sahara", "World", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), `1950` = c(7752.118, 1263.171, 8872.247, 4354.882, 46.301, 2895.997, 17150.335, 8177.344, 6936.445, 79.088, 115.614, 37894.68, 1353.506, 210.995, 8628.489, 176.795, 3089.649, 2661.293, 412.533, 53974.726, 68.918, 89.793, 48.001, 7250.999, 17527.243, 2308.923, 7745.003, 4432.716, 4466.498, 13736.997, 178.066, 1326.653, 8075.81, 2502.314, 6142.899, 544112.923, 7561.863, 12340.899, 156.334, 15.141, 807.726, 12183.661, 959.489, 3850.295, 5919.997, 494.014, 8902.619, 2255.221, 4268.27, 2364.65, 3470.162, 2199.897, 225.536, 18128.034, 1142.15, 1100.998, 288.993, 4008.299, 41879.607, 25.479, 60.268, 62.001, 473.3, 3527.004, 271.372, 931.926, 69786.246, 4980.878, 33.05, 7566.002, 76.676, 209.999, 59.65, 3146.073, 3093.651, 406.562, 3221.277, 1487.235, 1973.998, 9337.723, 142.656, 376325.205, 69543.319, 17119.263, 5719.191, 2913.093, 1257.971, 46598.602, 2630.131, 1402.896, 82199.47, 6702.996, 448.861, 6076.757, 10549.469, 19211.386, 152.25, 1740, 1682.916, 1334.618, 733.942, 1949, 930.026, 1113.382, 2567.402, 296.001, 196.482, 4083.554, 2953.871, 6109.907, 73.715, 4708.425, 311.997, 222.001, 660.491, 493.254, 28012.558, 780.2, 2341.003, 394.738, 8985.99, 6313.29, 456.418, 485.274, 8483.321, 10027.047, 100.184, 38.066, 64.824, 47.695, 1908.001, 1294.993, 2559.703, 37859.745, 3265.278, 32, 37542.38, 859.66, 1708.192, 1473.245, 7727.735, 18580.487, 24824.013, 8416.969, 535.429, 433.398, 2218, 24.999, 248.111, 16236.292, 102798.657, 2186.187, 82.783, 67, 60, 3121.336, 2476.638, 6732.256, 36.322, 1944.001, 1022.098, 3436.574, 24809.903, 1473.094, 2264.081, 13683.162, 2746.854, 28069.737, 2582.929, 5733.944, 13.766, 214.999, 273, 7009.913, 4668.088, 3413.329, 1531.502, 20710.356, 1395.458, 47.22, 645.628, 69.59, 3605.31, 21238.496, 1211, 5158.193, 37297.652, 1254.444, 20897.237, 50616.012, 102.235, 7649.766, 157813.04, 26.795, 4284.457, 2238.506, 6945.397, 5481.977, 82.102, 4402.32, 2316.95, 2525149.312, 812988.79, 1712160.522, 228901.723, 168843.911, 171614.868, 666585.791, 549089.107, 12681.946, 66922.702, 26400.57, 49221.876, 15587.911, 70768.664, 17075.654, 38028.823, 164900.344, 511574.182, 50957.44, 220170.535, 78029.913, 108632.979, 142255.68, 10085.345, 2199.497, 113739.434, 1516435.967, 1394017.757, 195724.555, 179679.847, 1158315.256, 155.093, 242.011, 130103.438, 768893.01, 824937.314, 800383.367, 1593830.324, 18130.895, 493443.287)), .Names = c("name", "1950"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -241L))
```

I appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you are using the `World` dataset from the `tmap` package. There are three issues with your code. First, there are no column called `1950`. The column indicating to population density is `pop_est_dens`. Second, assuming that `pop_est_dens` is the column you want to plot, the `breaks` is too large as the maximum is only about 1200. Third, `topo` is not a valid `palette` name.

Therefore, I modified your code as follows.

```
library(tmap)
data(World)

map <- tm_shape(World)+
  tm_fill("pop_est_dens", 
          title = "Population class",
          breaks = c(0, 100 ,200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200),
          style = "fixed",
          textNA = "No data",
          colorNA = "white", 
          palette = "Reds")+
  tm_borders() +
  tm_layout("World Density Population Map")
map
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add fixed breaks to a size variable in a `tm_bubble()` plot?

Comment: @spacedSparking This question seems to be unrelated to `tm_bubble`.

Comment: Good point. I've created a new question regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319733/adding-fixed-size-breaks-with-tmap-tm-bubble).